# ¿Qué quiere decir "alivio de luto"?

Tags: definiciones, significado

Leí hace poco la expresión "alivio de luto" en un libro. La lógica me indica que se trata de un luto aligerado tras la primera época posterior a la muerte de un ser querido. ¿Estoy en lo cierto? ¿varía la expresión según la zona?

Haciendo un poco de búsqueda encuentro en la [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=L4o73ORy3DXX2g84x9HI):

> **alivio** (de aliviar)
>
> 2. m. Atenuación de las señales externas de duelo una vez transcurrido el tiempo de luto riguroso.

Por lo que "alivio de luto" y "alivio" a secas podrían ser lo mismo. Seguí buscando y encontré en Wordreference [alguien que comenta](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/alivio-de-luto.331969/#post-1978821):

> Sí, mi abuela guardaba medio luto permanente. El luto completo
>   consistía en traer la cara tapada con un velo negro y toda la ropa
>   negra. Después se quitaba el velo y mantenía la ropa negra (que sería
>   como tres cuartas partes de luto, ja) y después se "permitía" usar
>   gris, azul marino o café oscuro.

¿Es toda esta información correcta o estoy dejándome algo en el tintero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El **alivio de luto** es un luto "liviano". Se refiere más que nada a los colores de vestimenta que usan los deudos.

Durante el luto riguroso se viste de negro, se evita la vida social y el ocio. En el pasado este periodo podía durar algunos meses o años, dependiendo del parentesco y la importancia del fallecido. Hace poco, cuando murió mi abuelo, mi madre hizo luto dos días.

Después de este periodo *se aliviana el luto*, o sea se vuelve a la vida normal pero con ropa de color oscuro (azul, gris, café) o, como en el caso de mi madre, se lleva un prendedor o lazo negro a la vista.

Actualmente esto es casi materia de la antropología, pero en un pasado reciente -mediados del siglo XX- existía un protocolo y duraciones claras al respecto.

Por cierto, **luto** deriva del latín *luctus* ("aflicción"), de donde también derivan *luctuoso* ("triste") y *lúgubre* ("oscuro", "melancólico").
Mientras que **alivio** deriva del latín *levare* ("levantar"), del cual derivan *leve*, *elevar*, *relieve* y muchas más. *Aliviar* significa etimológicamente "mover hacia arriba", y por lo tanto en un juego conceptual, implica "quitar peso" para que algo pueda subir.

Answer (score 2):

Sí, y es "medio luto" (mezzo, en italiano).

En [*El luto en sociedad. Parte primera*](https://www.protocolo.org/social/urbanidad/el_luto_en_sociedad_parte_primera.html) ofrecen una tabla explicativa de la duración del tipo de luto según la proximidad:

> ```
> Viudo             1 año de luto       3 meses de medio luto
> Padres              1 año de luto       3 meses de medio luto
> Suegros             9 meses de luto     2 meses de medio luto
> Hermanos y cuñados  6 meses de luto     1 mes de medio luto
> Tíos                3 meses de luto     1 mes de medio luto
> Primos              1 mes de luto (a voluntad)
> ```

Y a continuación describen cómo se estila vestirse en ellas:

> Durante las seis primera semanas de un luto riguroso, las señoras llevarán traje de cachemir negro con alto biés de crespón, sombrero de crespón y velo a la cara. Después este último se sustituye por el gran velo flotante a la espalda, y en los últimos meses solo velo de tul. Los guantes son de Suecia, negros, los zapatos mates, los pañuelos con jaretón y cifras negros, y las sombrillas, paraguas, manguitos, portamonedas y tarjeteros, negros.
>
> El medio luto se lleva en lanilla o seda, según la estación; los colores son gris, violeta, blanco y negro, malva, pensamiento, heliotropo y lila. Se admite ya el sombrero con plumas, pájaros y flores. Los diamantes y las perolas se permiten en las orejas desde las seis semanas del luto.

Answer (score 1):

El "alivio" consiste en introducir en los vestidos ciertos colores para que no todo sea negro o blanco y negro. Se admiten el gris y el malva/morado.
Azul, ni siquiera marino, es luto. Color café tampoco. Sólo negro, blanco, gris y morado.